# How to set individual feature angle in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I have an application where each element has an angle. I can use "Angle" function in "style" but not individual. Is there any way to apply angle individually?
[image]

```
function DesenhaPonto(Id, Estilo, Longitude, Latitude, Source, Angulo) {
            try {

                var coordinates = [Longitude, Latitude];
                var feat = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates));
                feat.setStyle(Estilo);
               // feat.angle(Angulo); <---- We need set individual Angle here.
                feat.name = Id;
                Source.addFeature(feat);
            } catch (e) {
                TrataErro(e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume your Estilo contains a regular shape image which can have an angle property, but to avoid run time errors that should be tested, then you can set it in the style.  You should also clone the style if one style might be used by features with different angles.

```
 if (Estilo.getImage() && Estilo.getImage().setAngle) {
   Estilo.getImage().setAngle(Angulo);
 }
 feat.setStyle(Estilo.clone());
```